# Get random email address from CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I am developing a PHP application where I need to fetch 5 random email addresses from a CSV file and send to user.

I already worked with CSV file many times but don't know how to fetch randomly in limit.

```
NOTE: CSV file have more than 200k emails.
```

Any one have a idea or suggestion then please send me.

Comment: What is the structure of your CSV ? And do you want 1 mail every 5 mails, or 5 different mails out of all the mails ?

Comment: how about reading the CSV file, put the emails into an array and run a random number generator whose output you use to pick the value at that index of array ?

Comment: @Sanjeev the CSV might be bigger than available memory.

Comment: @MihaiStancu good point. but then any csv bigger than 32MB should never be read directly. put that into DB and read from there. any alternative?

Comment: @Sanjeev read my answer, it covers all possibilities. Also 32MB is not necessarily the default max memory for every hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

### If CSV is too big and won't be saved in a DB

You'll have to loop through all of the rows in the CSV once to count them.

You'll have to call a random-number generator function (`rand`, `mt_rand`, others...) and parametrize it to output numbers from `0` to `$count`, and call it 5 times (to get 5 numbers).

You'll have to loop through all of the rows in the CSV again and only copy the necessary information for the rows whose number matches the randomly generated values.

Nota bene: don't use `file_get_contents` with `str_getcsv`. Instead use `fopen` with `fgetcsv`. The first approach loads the entire file to memory which we don't want to do. The second approach only read the file line-by-line.

### If the CSV is too big and will be saved in a DB

Loop through the CSV rows and insert each record into the DB.

Use a select query with `LIMIT 5` and `ORDER BY RAND()`.

### If the CSV is small enough to fit into memory

Loop through the CSV rows and create an array holding all of them.

You'll have to call a random-number generator function (`rand`, `mt_rand`, others...) and parametrize it to output numbers from `0` to array count, and call it 5 times (to get 5 numbers).

Then retrieve the rows from the big array by their index number -- using the randomly generated numbers as indexes.

Comment: Ok. means large csv then its better to save in DB..right

Comment: @harsh4u no, not necessarily -- the first approach should work almost as fast as any other and won't consume much memory at all. I would only use a DB if I also wanted to store the CSV info in the DB for later use, otherwise I'd use the first option.

Comment: By the way a few hundred thousand CSV lines isn't a very large CSV (it's likely less than 100MB) -- don't missunderstand me, its a large CSV but it's not a very large CSV.

Comment: I was actually thinking about adding a bash option for that but I thought to myself that most shared hostings don't allow you to execut binaries (no access to `exec`, `passthru`, `system` etc.) :-).

Answer (score 0):

If csv file is not too big you can load whole file to array to get something like

```
e[0] = 'someone1@somewhere.com';
e[1] = 'someone2@somewhere.com';
e[2] = 'someone3@somewhere.com';
```

then you can pick random email by e[rand(0, sizeof(e))];

and do this 5 times (with check for double items)

Comment: CSV file have more than 2 lakhs emails so its not possible

Comment: @harsh4u the lakh numbering notation is not very familiar to europeans / americans.

Answer (score 0):

Read all emails from CSV then select random 5 email from email array.
To select 5 random number use array_rand function.

```
$email = array('test@test.com','test2@test.com','test3@test.com','test4@test.com','test5@test.com');
$output = array_rand($email, 5);

print_r($email); // will return random 5 email.
```

for large number try to use something like

```
$max = count($email);
$email_rand = array();
for ($i =0; $i<5; $i++) 
{
    $a = mt_rand(0, $max);
    $email_rand[] = $email[$a];
}
print_r($email_rand);
```

Comment: Update question. Lots of email so its not possible

Comment: save in db temporary and use rand in query with limit 5.

Comment: @shivanshupatel saving in temporary db just to extract 5 emails is a big work overhead for such a small task. If you already intended to save them to a DB that's fine and I'd recommend this approach to but creating a temporary table, inserting each row, retrieving the data, dropping the table seems like a large amount of code for such a small task.

Comment: @shivanshupatel There is little or no difference between your first example (`array_rand`) and your second example (the `for` loop), except maybe the fact that `array_rand` is a native function and will always work faster and use less memory than user-defined PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$handle = fopen('test.csv', 'r');
$csv = fgetcsv($handle);

function randomMail($key)
{
    global $csv;
    $randomMail = $csv[$key];
    return $randomMail;
}

$randomKey = array_rand($csv, 5);
print_r(array_map('randomMail', $randomKey));
```

This is small utility to achieve the thing you expect and change the declaration of `randomMail` function as you desired.

Comment: `file_get_contents` reads the entire file into memory -- but the CSV might be pretty big (~100MB) and might not fit into memory.

Comment: `str_getcsv` has a cousin `fgetcsv` which reads from file-handles opened with `fopen` -- and `fopen` doesn't read the entire file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
$cmd = "awk NR==$(($"."{RANDOM} % `wc -l < ~/Downloads/email.csv` + 1)) ~/Downloads/email.csv >> listemail.txt";
$rs = exec($cmd);
}
```

after you read list mail from listmail.txt